# In Google Analytics real-time how is it determined if a user is a mobile, tablet or desktop user?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics real-time visitors, how does Google determine if a user is a mobile, tablet or desktop user?
By resolution of the device? By browser headers (seems unlikely because I believe it's hard to differentiate different headers) or some way else?

Answer (score 1):

I believe GA uses the user agent info to identify the device (whether it's real time or not).

Run the following in your console, and you'll see the data:

```
navigator.userAgent
```